# Selling electricity back to provider

Tags: power, current, transformer, solar-cell

Say someone has a large array of solar panels or a wind turbine or two. They produce all the electricity they need for their house and then some. I always hear that, "The extra electricity can be sold back to the power company. They will pay you." How does this actually work? I know I cannot run my neighbors house off of my power line without disconnecting them from the power grid because it will short circuit. How does one push power back up the grid to receive credit with the power company? Is this some hoax from the power companies to get us to buy renewable power? I'm all for renewable energy, but this 'selling power back" thing sounds fishy.

Comment: This is a real technology, though far from promoting it the utility companies actually *hate* it especially as it is becoming more common.  That said, it's not really on topic here either.

Comment: Look up "grid-tie inverter"

Comment: Incorrectly configured backfeeds are notorious for killing linemen, and you'll be responsible. Make sure you get this done properly if you get it done at all.

Comment: You can only sell power back if your meter and power company support it, a lot of power companies won't do this because they have to deal with dynamic pricing on their end and the consumer is typically fixed. If everyone has solar during the day the price goes down and sometimes can be negative

Answer (score 4):

The power company have to install (or approve the installation of) a special meter (to monitor incoming *and* outgoing power) and a grid-tie inverter. It's not something you can just start doing by yourself.

Usually, in locations where these arrangements are permitted or encouraged, it's done under a regional government scheme, where you get some form of incentive for installing the kit, and the power company is obliged to buy your power at a premium price, whether they want it at that moment or not. It often happens that you are paid a price per unit you generate, whether you use it, or whether it gets supplied back onto the grid.

The grid-tie inverter simply pushes current into the constant voltage of the grid, just the opposite of you pulling current out of the grid's constant voltage when you use power. That way, there's no short circuit.

Comment: do you happen to know what the physical limits are in terms of "sending power back into the grid ? " I assume those `grid-tie inverters` send power in the same direction of the current it is coming in?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife not sure I understand how the two parts of your question relate. Physical limits? The circuit must be able to handle the total power exported, unlikely to be more than the max power you could expect to import. Direction? The voltage will be identical to the grid, the current will be in the opposite direction to that it would be were you were importing power.